# Url parameters does not work in NGINX SubFolder Redirect

Tags: nginx, https

When I am using the webservice locally (127.0.0.1), the endpoints with the parameters work normally and the webservice returns the normal content.

The URL in localmachine is: http://localhost:8888/servico/search/findByEmpresaId?empresaId=1

This query returns correct by the webservice.

To add https to the webervice, I used NGINX with redirection to sub folder. The new url is:

https://systemapp/servico/search/findByEmpresaId?empresaId=1

But on the NGIX server send to webservice the url without the params

http://localhost:8888/search/findByEmpresaId

The .conf that i used is:

```
location ~/webservice(.*)$ {
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888$1;
}
```

With this redirect, the endpoint https://systemapp/webservice/empresa?test=1;teste2=2 only works when a use https://systemapp/webservice/empresa/1/2

Comment: You haven't captured the query string. Try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8888$1$is_args$args;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RichardSmith

```
location ~/webservice(.*)$ {
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888$1$is_args$args;
}
```